# Only show values of combobox like "love"?

Tags: c#

I created a store procedure to select all values of the table.
But I want in C# application, combobox only show values start like `love` keyword.

Example:

```
love love
love king
love soft
```

Don't show item:

```
long time
union all
```

My code:

```
public void HienThiLoaiBCao()
{
    LovetoDAL cal = new LovetoDAL();
    string keyword = "BC";

    int i = cbxTenBaoCao.FindString(keyword);
    if (i == -1)
        return;
    else
    {
        var dt = cal.Love_GetByTop("", "", "ID DESC");
        cbxTenBaoCao.DataSource = dt;
        cbxTenBaoCao.DisplayMember = "lover";
        cbxTenBaoCao.ValueMember = "lover";
    }
}

public DataTable Love_GetByTop(string Top, string Where, string Order)
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("sq_Love_GetByTop", GetConnection()))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Top", Top));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Where", Where));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Order", Order));
        var dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}


USE [LEO]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sq_Love_GetByTop]
@Top nvarchar(10),
@Where nvarchar(500), 
@Order nvarchar(500)
AS
    Declare @SQL as nvarchar(500) 
Select @SQL = 'SELECT top (' + @Top + ') * FROM [Love]'
if len(@Top) = 0
BEGIN
Select @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM [Love]'
END
if len(@Where) >0
BEGIN
Select @SQL = @SQL + ' Where ' + @Where
END
if len(@Order) >0
BEGIN
Select @SQL = @SQL + ' Order by ' + @Order
END
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you coding in Windows Forms or WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to filter out the records that starts with `love` from your `DataTable`. You can either use `Select` method on `DataTable` directly OR use `RowFilter` property on default `DataView` of the table and then bind the filtered results to your combo box.

Something like this with `DataView` -

```
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
//Apply your filter on data view, for records starting with `love`
dv.RowFilter = "lover like 'love*'";
//and bind you combo box with the data view
cbxTenBaoCao.DataSource = dv;
```

Rest of the code would be as is.

More on filtering result sets -

http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. That helpful for me.

Answer (score -1):

i did not try this code, it's a long time since i code c#.

```
//get the values from your stored procedure
List<string> values = task.storedProcedures();
//remove items that doesn't start with "love"
values = values.Where(item => item.someValues.StartsWith("love"))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. I tested your code but not run on my application.